# How to display an gridview within a tabbed layout

Tags: android, gridview

Hi I'm setting up an android app and I'm using a tabbed interface. I'd like two tabs, a text based tab (Song),a gridview tab of images like in the Gridview tutorial.

Using the tabbed interface tutrial as an example, I am declaring the tab's content within the onCreate() event of the main class.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, GalleryActivity.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);           

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this,songs.class);

        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                        .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);        

    }
```

And my gallery activity is

```
public class GalleryActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       


    GridView gridview = new GridView(this);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    setContentView(R.layout.grid);



}
```

}

```
    }
}
```

And my xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

My Adapter class is

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mContext= c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mThumbIds.length;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);            

            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

            //myButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL));



        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;

    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };
}
```

After doing this when i compiled and run the program i didnt get the grid layout
[image]

Output is not properly formated.I think by adding the grid view xml attributes to Adapter class  can fix the errors. But i dont know how to use that attributes in java ui attributes are

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
```

can any one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using **setContentView(gridview);** in GalleryAcitvity use a separate XML file (say grid.xml) and write the following code in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

then use

```
setContentView(R.layout.grid);
```

in GalleryActivity at the start of onCreate method.
Try this.

Comment: didnt work for me.I am getting black screen only in galleryActivity

Comment: Can you edit the above posted code to let me know what you did because it should work.

Comment: I did what you said . I created new xml file and added setContentView(R.layout.grid) in my GalleryActivity class.I edited the above code

Comment: you are still making mistake , Use the following code in onCreate method of GalleryActivity class:          **public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
}**